# Laravel 5 installing `frozennode` can not publish `assets` package

Tags: content-management-system, laravel-5

I want to use laravel administrator for `cms` in laravel 5 but after `php artisan vendor:publish`  when i want to publish assets packages an exception occur that says `there are no commands defined in the "asset" namespace` here is my command

```
php artisan asset:publish frozennode/administrator
```

for any help and guide thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To install Administrator as a Composer package to be used with Laravel 5, simply add this to your composer.json:

```
"frozennode/administrator": "5.*"
```

and run `composer update`  Once it's installed, you can register the service provider in `config/app.php` in the `providers` array:

```
 'providers' => [
    'Frozennode\Administrator\AdministratorServiceProvider',
]
```

Then publish Administrator's assets with `php artisan vendor:publish`. 
This will add the file `config/administrator.php`. This config file is the primary way you interact with Administrator. This command will also publish all of the assets, views, and translation files.

Comment: where i can find its document. I haven't found reasonable documentation